# Selenium Python Automation picking best locator type

Tags: python, authentication, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to use the best "Locating Elements" statement in order to automate the process of logging on to a particular website automatically (using selenium and python). I have attached an image of the html code for login page:

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EymUW.png)

and am looking for the locator element (ex: username = driver.find_element_by .... ) for the highlighted portion within the image.

Comment: Please post the code in the question, rather than screenshots, as some users may not have access to image hosting sites

Comment: "Best" location strategy is when you use a location by id, because id is unique for the DOM.  If you can't use id location, use css because css is faster then other strategies.  Alternavlity you can use XPath ...

Answer (score 0):

could you expand on your question? "and am looking for the locator element (ex: username = driver.find_element_by .... ) for the portion that reads:"

if you are looking to find the element that is highlighted. I would use the `find_element_by_id("UserName")`

Comment: I tried that first but received the following error message:                                                                 NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"UserName"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is really a matter of what you think is least likely to change. Generally, that's going to be the element's `id`.

In your example, I'd use `username = driver.find_element_by_id('UserName').getAttribute('value')`

However, sometimes an element doesn't have an `id`. Again, "best" should be based on what's least likely to change. In order of what I've seen in my experience from best to worst:

1. `id`
2. `name`
3. some version of `find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'xyz')]")`
4. xpath
5. css_selector

Comment: username = driver.find_element_by_id('UserName').getAttribute('value') gave me another NoSuchElementException error

Comment: @Its_code_outside: You're running the code on the same page you posted? There is clearly an element with id of 'UserName', so it should work, unless maybe the element is lazy loaded or takes too long to load. In that case, you may need to import time and add `time.sleep(5)` to have it wait for 5 seconds for the page to fully load.

Comment: I already had time.sleep(5) in there actually... which is why I am so confused as to why it is not working.

Comment: this seems to be the overall path: html   >  frameset   >  frame  >  html   >  body   >   div   >   div.logoncontent   >   div#logon_content   >   form   >   div#r1   >  div   >  input#UserName (that is what shows at the bottom of the page after clicking "inspect element")